# How to retain the searched data in the view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have View `LSires` where I have 4 dropdowns and based on dropdown search, I get the result. In the result table, in each row, 1st column is actionlink which redirect to another view `SDetails`. I have `close` button on `SDetails` view.

What I want is that when I click on `Close`, it should redirect to `LSires` with data which I have searched it before. It do not want to reload the whole form again.

Model

```
public class LeadingSires
{        
    public int? SireType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SireTypeList { get; set; }
    public string sTypeName{ set; get; }

    public int? Country { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }

    public string Season { get; set; }

    public string NoofSires { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> NoofSiresList { get; set; }

    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SortOrderList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LeadingSiresClass> Leadings { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult LSires(LeadingSires model)
{
    LeadingSires leadingSires = new LeadingSires();
    leadingSires = Dropdownlist();
    LeadingSiresData leadingSiresData = new LeadingSiresData();
    IEnumerable<LeadingSiresClass> data;    

    if (model.Season == null) 
    {
        model.Season = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year);
    }

    if (model.SireType != null)
    {
        data = leadingSiresData.LeadingSiresBasedonFilter(model);        
    }
    else
    {
        leadingSires.SireType = 2;
        leadingSires.Country = 115;
        leadingSires.NoofSires = "20";
        leadingSires.SortOrder = "Earnings";
        leadingSires.Season = (DateTime.Now.Year).ToString();
        data = leadingSiresData.LeadingSiresBasedonFilter(leadingSires);
    }

    leadingSires.Leadings = data;

    return View(leadingSires);
}
```

SRoster

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SRoster(SForm model)
        {

            return View(model);
        }
```

SDetails

```
  public ActionResult SDetail(int id, string redirectUrl = null)
        {            
            TempData["redirectUrl"] = redirectUrl;           
            TempData["Id"] = id;
            SHandler sHandler = new SHandler();
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(sHandler.GetStallionData(id));

        }
```

LSires View

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("LSires", "LSires", FormMethod.Get))
            {

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().SireType)
                        <div>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.sTypeName)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SireType, Model.SireTypeList)
                        </div>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Country)
                        <div>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountriesList)
                        </div>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Season")
                        <div>
                            @Html.DropDownList("Season", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year - 13, 14).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x)))
                        </div>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().NoofSires)
                        <div>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NoofSires, Model.NoofSiresList)
                        </div>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Leadings.FirstOrDefault().SortOrder)
                        <div>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SortOrder, Model.SortOrderList)
                        </div>

                        <div style="padding-top:15px;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info  pull-right">Search</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            }

<table>  
 @foreach (var item in Model.Leadings)
            {
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RankId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink(item.StallionCodeToStud, "StallionDetail", "StallionRoster", new { id = item.RosterId, redirectUrl = "~/LeadingSires/LeadingSires/" }, null)

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Breeding)
                            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

SDetails

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SRoster", "SRoster", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info RbtnMargin">Close</button>
            }

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 nopadding">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {

                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <h3>@item.Season Stud Fee: @item.StudFee</h3>
                                                <h4>@item.StudDescription</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                <h3 style="text-align: end">@item.Summary</h3>
                                                <h4 style="text-align: end">@item.FullFamily</h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: LSires method is accepting argument LeadingSires model, It seems you are making GET request from LSires, and then SDetails view is being posted on SRoster action inside SRoster controller. What is the code for that, and where that details view is closing.

Comment: @M_Idrees, updated code for SDetails. If you check the `SDetails` view, I have implemented `Close` inside post. I am looking for a way to close `SDetails` page without affecting `LSires` view. If I have searched some data inside `LSires` then that data should be there when closed `SDetails` page.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `LSires` action method, put your data in `Session` just before returning view. Like this:

```
Session["LeadingSires_Data"] = leadingSires;
return View(leadingSires);
```

When your are closing `SDetails` page, and return control back to `LSire` action method, just pass a query string parameter like:

```
ReturningFromDetailsPage=true
```

And then on the top of action method `LSires`, check this query string parameter (`ReturningFromDetailsPage`) if it is returning back from `SDetails` page then simply load data from Session:

```
LeadingSiresData leadingSiresData = Session["LeadingSires_Data"] as LeadingSiresData;
```

Otherwise (in else case) write your original logic of loading data.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand 2nd and 3rd part in your answer. Where shall I write `ReturningFromDetailsPage=true`. Can you please elaborate with some more code which help me to understand.

Comment: Thats why I asked for code where your sDetail page is posting. (  @using (Html.BeginForm("SRoster", "SRoster", FormMethod.Post))) inside this action method, you have to pass query string when redirecting to LSires.

Comment: I have already posted that in the question. I have to pass like `@using (Html.BeginForm("SRoster", "SRoster", FormMethod.Post,ReturningFromDetailsPage=true))`

Comment: This code seems to post on Controller 'SRoster' and action method also 'SRoster'. Where is the code for this action method.

Comment: I added `SRoster` method in the question